# writing a script in terminal to move files from sub folders to a parent folder

Tags: macos, unix, terminal

I have a parent foloder X that includes sub-folder X1 , X2 and X3 .... each of these sub-folders include music files. I would like to move thes files to the main folder X and delete the sub-folders X1, X2 ..etc.

How can I do that in terminal (mac)?

thanks a million in advance,

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need an entire script to do this; it should be doable from the command line.  Let's say all the music files you want to move end in .mp3, and none of the other files (the ones you don't want to move) end that way.  If that's the case, you can use cd to get into directory X, then run:

```
mv X1/*.mp3 .
```

...and so on for the other two sub-directories.
Alternatively, if you want to do all files at the same time, you could do this:

```
i=0; while [ $i -lt 3 ]; do i=$(( $i + 1 )); mv X$i/*.mp3 .; done
```

in which the number after the "-lt" is the suffix of the final directory you want to extract files from.

When you're done, you can use

```
rmdir X1
```

to remove the directories if they're empty, or

```
rm -r X1
```

if they're not.  You can also build it into the one-liner above like this:

```
i=0; while [ $i -lt 3 ]; do i=$(( $i + 1 )); mv X$i/*.mp3 .; rm -r X$i; done
```

...just make sure that there isn't anything else in those directories you want to keep before doing so.

**UPDATE**: If the subdirectories are not systematically named, there's another way to do it.  Note this will only work without errors if you want to extract the files from all subdirectories of the parent directory:

```
for i in `ls -l | egrep '^d'| awk '{print $10}'`; do  mv $i/*.mp3 .; done
```

Comment: Great but the sub file are not only three they are many (around 100) and they are not named X1 X2 etc... anyway to do it for different named sub-directories? thanks for the answer in advance.

Comment: See the update, above.  It will now find all subdirectories of X, regardless of name, and extract all files ending in .mp3 from within those directories.

Answer (score 0):

The following will emit a few error messages if you have any files in the top level directory and an error about not being able to remove 'X', but they can be safely ignored:

```
find X -type f -exec mv {} X \;    # Move all files into X
find X -depth -type d -exec rmdir {} \;  # Remove all subdirectories of X
```

This will move *all* files.  If you want to limit the files to a certain set, use a `-name` (or other) qualifier on the first `find` command to filter the files that are moved.